# Crystal Reports "Failed to open the connection" error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have ASP.NET (C#) application which uses SAP Crystal Reports. In Visual Studio everything works well, but when I deploy it to IIS the following error occurs:

```
"Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection 'report name'.rpt".
```

I have changed my reports to use System DSN now the previous error gone but it generates following error:

```
"Database Logon Failed"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked your connection properties?

Comment: Does the IIS account have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes. Everything works in Visual Studio. I also have some other tables which pools data from same connection they also work well even when deployed

Comment: @ta.speot.is I don't know what permissions should the user have. I am using NetworkService

Comment: set **user and password** for connection

Comment: @meysam I set it programically, everything works perfect in VS. I also considered this and set report viewer to ask me everytime and tried this version. Again it asks me for username and password in VS. when I enter them everything is fine. But when I test it in IIS it asks me for user name and password when I enter them, nothing happens, it just asks me again and again.

Comment: I solved this problem to. If anyone else have the same problem look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663050/crystal-reports-database-logon-failed. I hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim db As New _yourdbcontext()
    Dim cr As New ReportDocument
    cr.Load(Server.MapPath("~/yourreport.rpt"))
    cr.SetDataSource(db.yourtable.ToList())
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr
```

dont forget set user and password in **crystal report** and **model** connection