# Crystal Reports: Database Logon Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have application in ASP.NET (C#) in which I use Sap Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. In VS everything works perfect. But when I deploy it to IIS "Database Logon Failed" error occurs. When I set CrystalReportViever "Enable Database Logon Prompting" it keeps me asking for username and password but doesn't generate an error, nor shows the report. I am setting "Enable Database Logon Prompting" for testing purpose only otherwise I sending logon parameters by
ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(user, password, "my dsn name", ""). Again, everything works perfect in VS.
      I am using:
              - Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit
              - Visual Studio 2010 (C#)
              - Sap Crystal Reports, version for VS 2010
              - My App pool identity in IIS is NetworkServise
              - I am pooling data from Oracle Stored Procedure
              - I am using System DSN to connect to database

I am looking forward for your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @skhurams Because, all the Crystal reports guides said use System DSN. But I changed it to Oracle Server. Everything works well now. Thanks God.

Comment: Thank you for your time, if my problem wasn't solved I am sure that you would tell me same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your time.

I used User DSN before and I had "Failed to open the connection. Failed to open the connection 'report name'.rpt" when I deployed my application. Afterwards I changed it to SystemDSN. Previous error was gone but this time "Database Logon failed" error occured.

Finally I have solved my problem by changing connection form System DSN to Oracle Server. Everything works very well now. Consider this if you have same problem.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? System DSN is on the ODBC Data Source Administrator, right? So, where is this Oracle Server at?

Answer (score 4):

Ugh, Oracle. :)  Typically I don't use System DSN's with Crystal, but for Oracle it's been the only way I've been able to get it to connect.  As I recall, you will need to make sure that the DSN for Oracle is setup on the server in the "32-bit ODBC Data Soruce Administrator".  That's been the only way I've been able to successfully get Oracle to connect via Crystal.

Via .Net (C# or VB), that's another story.  I don't think you're App Pool identity is going to matter in this case since you're probably going to be using an Oracle username/password to connect.

90% of questions I answer deal with Crystal Reports and changing connection information.  I have some code I use in a wrapper that works for me in this blog post:

http://www.blakepell.com/2012-05-22-crystal-reports-extension-methods

The username is the oracle username, the password is the oracle password, the server name however is the name of the DSN.  Don't ask me why, but that always works for me. :p

Comment: Final note, I'm putting together some Crystal Report extension methods currently to make this easier to share in the future.  If I do, I'll try to remember to come back here and post a link to them.

Comment: Actually, you can get the extension methods I put together in VB or C# at:  http://www.blakepell.com/Blog/?p=487

Answer (score 2):

We had similar issue/error message: CR worked fine on most PCs including production server but on one particular dev. PC it did not. We checked Database Sources drivers and "SQL Native Client" was missing while "SQL Server Client" and "SQL Server Native Client" were present. We installed version 2005 from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11988 (for 64-bit OS) and it started working.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have also solved it by changing connection to Oracle Server

Answer (score 1):

I had an awful time with this Crystal issue, the report worked locally and on another server, but would not work on our production environment.

The issue was SQL Native client not being installed on the Prod server.  We modified the reports to use OLEDB.

```
Report Designer -> 
Right Click on Background -> 
Database -> 
Set Datasource location -> 
In the 'Replace With:' section, Create a New Connection using OLE DB (ADO) -> 
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
```

We had been selecting SQL Server Native Client 11.0, and this was causing the error on deployment.

Prior to this, I had tried everything, x86/x64, app pool changes, installing crazy versions of Crystal 13, this was it.

Comment: I am connecting to PeopleSoft to run a Query. This does not apply to such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string error. your code update with this steps:

1.clear dataset connection.
2.set table or tables.
3.don't set datasource and dataset. becuase you sent data in tables to crystal report and do not need to connect to server or database.
4.refresh the reportdocument.
for example:

```
MyCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
MyCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(MyDataSet.Tables[0]);
MyCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.Refresh();
MyCrystalReportSource.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Response, true, reportTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sub-reports in the main report. Then remove the datasets from Main Reports.  And use only datasets of Sub-Reports. Now your report will be displayed on server