# Crystal Reports - Database logon failed only on production machine

Tags: c#, iis, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal reports on my application and is working properly on the development machine. When I put the application on IIS of the production machine I get the following error "Database logon failed."

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I use the following code:

```
public void sendEmail(int id)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

        cryRpt.Load(@"C:\temp\rep1.rpt");
        cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "pass");
        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@ID", id);

        emailCreator(from, to, subject, body, "Attachment.pdf", cryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
    }
```

Comment: This problem may be caused by 32 bit Applications being disabled, try to enable it. This has a similar problem you can refer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759533/published-reports-dont-work-database-logon-failed-error

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already enabled 32-bit Application on IIS and the aspnet_client folder  is on wwwroot but I still get the same error.

Comment: Whether IIS and database are located on the same computer?

Comment: No they are on different servers. The development machine is in different machine than database as well but is working. IIS has access to database  with the user I use for the reports.

Comment: Under IIS Application Pools. Check the Advanced Settings for the application pool you selected for your web application. Make sure it runs under Administrator and we need to have rights to access this folder in order for the report to be loaded in viewer at runtime. Also make sure you have the runtime installed for .Net Framework on the server. This setting needs to be done only if IIS is on a remote server. If IIS and Database are on same machine, this setting is not needed. The application pool can then run merely as a Local service.

Comment: I changed the Identity to Administrator but the error stays the same. I had already the runtime installed for .Net Framework on the server.

Comment: I found a similar question on SO, maybe you can get help from it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663050/crystal-reports-database-logon-failed

Comment: It could be due to what kind of data provider you are using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65097885/1037864